# reduce time of executing sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have this query take more time for execution approximate 25 min
to execute

```
 select   
     T.ID,T.START_DT,T.PARENT_TASKID, TDS.name As TASK_DONE_STR, T.PROCESS_ID, T.PROCESS_STEP, T.EMP_ID, TTP.NAME AS task_type_STR, 
     T.MSG, T.MSG_E, T.FRM_CLASS, T.FRM_STYLE, T.FRM_ID, T.FRM_INITIALS, 
     P.CODE AS P_CODE ,P.name AS P_NAME,PDS.name As PROC_DONE_STR,E.EMP_CODE, E.emp_name As EMP_NAME, 
     T.days_normal,T.days_alarm1,T.days_alarm2  


     ,T.GROUP_ID,G.NAME As Grp_NAME,T.PARAM_4,T.IS_LOCKED,T.PARAM_5,T.PARAM_6, -- // Added
      case T.IS_LOCKED when 1 then 'محمي' else 'غير محمي' end As IS_LOCKED_STR, --  // Added
      P.BRANCH_ID ,br.STORE_HOUSES AS Branch_Name  

     ,CASE T.FRM_STYLE when 'sell_talabia' then 'طلبية بيع' when 'sell_add' then 'طلب صرف'  
        when 'sell_inv' then 'إذن تسليم' when 'sell_sub' then 'مرتجع تسليم' when 'sell_togaar' then 'فاتورة تجار'   
        when 'import_order_in' then 'أمر توريد داخلي'  when 'import_order' then 'أمر توريد خارجي'   
        when 'import_inv' then 'إذن إستلام' when 'import' then 'فاتورة شراء'   
        when 'tr_internal' then 'إذن تحويل' when 'import_back_request' then 'طلب إرتجاع شراء'   
        when 'import_back_order' then 'إذن إرتجاع شراء' when 'seller_Issue' then 'طلب صرف-مندوب'   
     END AS TASK_STYLE   
     ,T.ACCESS_DATA ,P.cust_id,c.CUST_CODE,C.CUST_NAME   
     ,P.CUST_ID,c.BIAN1, R.CODE,R.NAME  -- //Added by Waleed
     ,STD.STD_NAME,STD.STD_CRNT_STEP,STD_GROUP_KEY 
     ,STD.STD_WF_TASK_TYPE, CTYP.Name As STD_WF_TASK_TYPE_STR, STD.STD_TASK_KEY,STD.STD_FRM_KEY,P.VARS_ARY,T.VARS_ARY_BGN,T.VARS_ARY AS T_VARS_ARY 
     ,case T.IS_SCRIPT_DONE when 1 then 'نعم' else 'لا' end As IS_SCRIPT_DON_STRE  ,T.LAST_EXCEPTION,STD.STD_ON_INIT_SCRIPT,STD.STD_ON_DONE_SCRIPT 
     ,P.PARAM_6 AS Process_ServiceType   
  from  CRM_WF_TASK T  
  left join const_names TDS on T.DONE_STATE_DEF=TDS.id  
  left join const_names TTP on T.task_type_def=TDS.id  
  left join crm_wf_process P on T.process_id=P.ID  
  left join const_names PDS on P.DONE_STATE_DEF=PDS.id  
  left join employee E on T.emp_id=E.emp_id  
  left join OP_EMP_GROUP G on T.GROUP_ID=G.ID 
  left join BRANCHES_NAME Br on P.BRANCH_ID= br.ID 

  left join CRM_WF_STRUCT_D STD on T.STRUCT_ID_D=STD.STD_ID 
  left join Const_Names CTYP on STD.STD_WF_TASK_TYPE=CTYP.ID 
  LEFT  JOIN CUSTOMERS AS C left JOIN ACC_REGION AS R ON R.ID = C.REGION_ID ON P.CUST_ID = C.ID
```

this query running in 100 level in my application
every level run this query and take 15 second 
then 15 *100 =1500 second

1500/60 =25 min 

it take 25 min for execution 

how can reduce This time of execution?

Comment: When asking for help with performance tuning it's a good idea to include the table structures (including indexes) and the query plan(s) for any queries that are causing a problem. Also, table sizes and expected number of rows returned.

Comment: you basically give no really usable info on your tables, usage, or data.  `how can reduce This time of execution? ` add a where clause that hits an index on `CRM_WF_TASK`, and hopefully filters out a significant number of rows. **Short of that you are just doing a table scan that joins in a bunch of secondary info, with no hope of improvements**  Do you really need all the data from `CRM_WF_TASK`? if so make it a report and don't display it on the screen.

Comment: How many rows are in CRM_WF_TASK?  You have no filters so it returns all rows from CRM_WF_TASK every time.  If this is a big table there is no way to make this faster

Answer (score 2):

Note -- you really need show the execution plan for us to see what the issue is but...

You can get sometimes get an improvement by replacing case with values statements.  Don't know if it will help but you can try like this.

```
select   
     --- blah blah blah 
     COALESCE(FS_LOOKUP.V,'') AS TASK_STYLE,
     --  blah blah blah
 from  CRM_WF_TASK T  
 LEFT JOIN (
    Values
       ('sell_talabia'       ,'طلبية بيع' ),
       ('sell_add'           ,'طلب صرف'  ),
       ('sell_inv'           ,'إذن تسليم' ),
       ('sell_sub'           ,'مرتجع تسليم' ),
       ('sell_togaar'        ,'فاتورة تجار'   ),
       ('import_order_in'    ,'أمر توريد داخلي'  ),
       ('import_order'       ,'أمر توريد خارجي'   ),
       ('import_inv'         ,'إذن إستلام' ),
       ('import'             ,'فاتورة شراء'   ),
       ('tr_internal'        ,'إذن تحويل' ),
       ('import_back_request','طلب إرتجاع شراء'   ),
       ('import_back_order'  ,'إذن إرتجاع شراء' ),
       ('seller_Issue'       ,'طلب صرف-مندوب'   )
  ) AS FS_LOOUP(K,V) ON T.FRM_STYLE = FL_LOOKUP.K
  -- blah blah blah
```

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that approach before.  I didn't think the syntax would work in SQL Server, until I tried it out.  However, I don't think it will fix a 25 minute query, but it may help a little.

Comment: @Hogan . . . Do you have evidence that this would be faster than a `case`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've seen it be faster in some cases on DB2.  and some stackoverflow users have reported an improvement with it.

Comment: @KM - yeah the values table constructor was added in 2008 I think.  It is a SQL standard :)

Comment: @KM -- also is this a 25 min query or a 15 sec. query run 100 times?

Comment: @Hogan, I've seen the `VALUES` used with insert statements, just never as part of a derived table.  I usually do the same thing with a series of SELECTs that are UNIONed together.

Comment: @KM yeah that is how I used to do it too, but this way is sexier (IMHO).

Comment: @GordonLinoff the execution plan be more And More details  
i find difficult to explain all business related to this query 
i try this improvement 
but also take the same time  
generally thanks more for your help

Comment: @OrchidaArabiaTeam - you don't have to explain the execution plan to Gordon or I... put it here or pastebin or something and we will look at it and explain it to you.